# Arrayformula with vlookup - Range Issue

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I am trying to range the Data from the tab "Extracted data" in the tab "Action Items"
Conversion Potential column (Action items tab) is taking the data from CTR Delta (Extracted data tab).
Relevance column (Action items tab) is taking the data from Position Delta (Extracted data tab).

For some reasons, it simply does not range the data in the right way.

Conversion Potential Range should go like:
[image]
CTR Range
-2  1
-1  2
0   3
1   4
2   5

Relevance is expected to be ranged like:

[image]
Range   Result
0-10    5
10-20   4
20-30   3
30-40   2
40-50   1
50-100  0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MlyMmZ3JcWmYeDS86YB7yQnTsb7Fv0btYa7b4o-zwgo/edit#gid=1011640328

Comment: In your example sheet, what values are you expecting in the cells `'Action Items'!M4:N9`?

Comment: I added images for clear vision how to evaluate the data from the 'Extracted Data' tab, columns M and N

Comment: The Relevance range looks fine, so what values are you expecting in the results? The CTR range looks like it needs to be `{-2,1;-1,2;0,3;1,4;2,5}`.

Comment: My bad! Sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `'Action Items'!M3` (delete cells below):

```
=arrayformula({"Conversion Potential";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(D4:D,'Extracted Data'!A:N,14,0),{-2,1;-1,2;0,3;1,4;2,5},2,1),)})
```

For `'Action Items'!N3` (delete cells below):

```
=arrayformula({"Relevance";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(D4:D,'Extracted Data'!A:N,13,0),{0,5;11,4;21,3;31,2;41,1;51,0},2,1),)})
```

[image]